# Вопрос по ImageView в Swift

Tags: swift

У меня есть класс родитель и потомок. В сториборд добавлен `UIImageView`. Мне нужно добавить несколько изображений в уже имеющийся массив, в котором меняется информация и должны меняться изображения при нажатии на кнопку:

1. в классах будет UIImage или UIImageView?
2. Каким образом я могу достать изображения из Assets и передать в массив?

arrayBuilding.append(childClass(type: "Офис", floor: 15, street: "Вджобывательная", parking: "есть", people: 445))

Answer (score 1):

На вью (сториборд, кастомные вью, контроллер) вы добавляете `UIImageView`. А уже для `UIImageView` вы устанавливаете `image`, и оно является `UIImage`. Если все изображения у вас доступны в *Assets*, то в массиве хранятся только их имена в виде строк.

Для того, чтобы достать изображения из *Assets* вам необходимо просто использовать имя вашего изображения для `UIImage`.

```
someImageView.image = UIImage(named: "SomeImageNameInAssets")
```